# Flash dynamic text not displaying when browser zoomed in

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a SWF file that is loading text from an xml file. The text loads and animates fine when viewing it embedded in an html page zoomed to 100%. It even looks fine when loading at 100% and then zooming in. My problem is that the text field will not display when the page reloads while zoomed at anything other than 100%. It gets even weirder because everything is fine if I set the text of the dynamic field via a static string, the same string as in the xml file.

The xml string is enclosed in CDATA tags and is well-formed.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Did you embed the fonts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed fonts to make dynamic textfiled work properly for all scale values and all rotations.

```
    Step1. Embed font - Using Embed keyword in Flah Builder ( Using gui in Flash Professional )

    Step2. Set a font family name for the embedded font

    Step3. In Actionscript, give this name as the font in the TextFormat of the textfield.

    Step4. Set embedFonts = true for the text field.
```

See how to do this : http://marumushi.com/news/embedding-fonts-in-as3